# Change spring-shell.log location

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I'm having some trouble with my spring-shell.log. Not a big problem but really annoying. Once I run my application from outside of my workspace, spring shell tries to save the spring-shell.log in a directory which is protected by windows. This results in not having a shelö history. Now I simply like to save the file somewhere else

My favorite way would be to change the location via application.properties. But I don't know if there is a properties for this. I'd be fine with changing the logback-spring.xml as well.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Windows\spring-shell.log
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.jline.reader.impl.history.DefaultHistory.save(DefaultHistory.java:121) ~[jline-3.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.jline.reader.impl.history.DefaultHistory.add(DefaultHistory.java:248) ~[jline-3.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.add(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.finishBuffer(LineReaderImpl.java:864) [jline-3.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:557) [jline-3.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:390) [jline-3.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.shell.jline.InteractiveShellApplicationRunner$JLineInputProvider.readInput(InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.java:115) [spring-shell-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.Shell.run(Shell.java:129) [spring-shell-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.jline.InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.run(InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.java:84) [spring-shell-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.provinzial.convenience.tools.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) [convenience-tools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) [convenience-tools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [convenience-tools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [convenience-tools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

I'm grateful for any hint. Thanks guys. Best regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

In your Spring project, just create a new class like this:

```
package com.example.shell.demo.config;

import org.jline.reader.History;
import org.jline.reader.LineReader;
import org.jline.reader.impl.history.DefaultHistory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Configuration
public class HistoryConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private History history;

    @Bean
    public History history(LineReader lineReader, @Value("${app.history.file}") String historyPath) {
        lineReader.setVariable(LineReader.HISTORY_FILE, Paths.get(historyPath));
        return new DefaultHistory(lineReader);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onContextClosedEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) throws IOException {
        history.save();
    }
}
```

Then, in your application.properties file, create a key / value pair like this

```
app.history.file=<path to your log file>
```

The original solution was posted here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/issues/220. I have tested it with Spring Shell 2.0.0-RELEASE and it works well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Humm.. this code gives circular dependancies. Has anyone faced same issue and found a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Humm.. this code gives circular dependancies. Has anyone faced same issue and found a workaround?

```bash
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  springShellHistoryConfiguration (field private org.jline.reader.History au.rolit.archiver.configuration.SpringShellHistoryConfiguration.history)
└──<-──┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I set spring.main.allow-circular-references=true, I get:

```bash
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   springShellHistoryConfiguration (field private org.jline.reader.History au.rolit.archiver.configuration.SpringShellHistoryConfiguration.history)
┌─────┐
|  history defined in class path resource [au/rolit/archiver/configuration/SpringShellHistoryConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.shell.boot.LineReaderAutoConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.shell.boot.CompleterAutoConfiguration (field private org.springframework.shell.Shell org.springframework.shell.boot.CompleterAutoConfiguration.shell)
↑     ↓
|  shell defined in class path resource [org/springframework/shell/boot/SpringShellAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  resultHandlerService defined in class path resource [org/springframework/shell/boot/SpringShellAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  throwableResultHandler defined in class path resource [org/springframework/shell/result/ResultHandlerConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  commandCatalog defined in class path resource [org/springframework/shell/boot/CommandCatalogAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  historyCommand defined in class path resource [org/springframework/shell/boot/StandardCommandsAutoConfiguration.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

For now I will have to do the spring way, without customising too much as mentioned here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/docs/index.html#built-in-commands-history

1. Turned off/on history by setting `spring.shell.history.enabled`
2. Name of a log file by setting `spring.shell.history.name`
3. Log file directory by setting `spring.shell.config.location`

Any comments?